# Receiving only 7 bits reading serial port midi bytes c++

Tags: c++, serial-port, byte, midi

G'day!
I want to send midi bytes to C++ through serial. I'm already receiving data. The only problem is that I only receive 7 bits and if I try to get 2 bytes the bits doesn't make sense. The range I'm receiving is between 0 and 127 and I should be able to see numbers between 0 and 255.

I'm storing the data in a char (1 byte). I've tried int and wchar_t but still not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

unsigned char data_in[0];
int data_in_int;

int main(void){

int fd_serialport;
struct termios options;

fd_serialport = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY);
//fd_serialport = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);


if(fd_serialport == -1){
    perror("Unable to open /dev/ttyACM0");
}

tcgetattr(fd_serialport, &options);
cfsetispeed(&options, B38400);
cfsetospeed(&options, B38400);
options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);    
//options.c_cflag |= PARENB;
//options.c_cflag |= PARODD;
//options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
options.c_cflag |= CS8;
//options.c_iflag |= (INPCK | ISTRIP);
tcsetattr(fd_serialport, TCSANOW, &options);

fcntl(fd_serialport, F_SETFL, 0);
usleep(1000000);

while(read(fd_serialport, &data_in[0], 1)){

    data_in_int=(int)data_in[0];
    printf("%i\n", data_in_int);

    }
    usleep(2000);
}
return(0);
```

I'm using a teensy (similar to arduino) to send the midi data. For the moment I'm just making test to see if I can get the number. I know teensy works because other programs interpret the data correctly (pure-data). I'm working with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
I've tried to send numbers between -255 and 255. The teensy code:

```
int indx=-256;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(38400);
}

void loop(){

  Serial.print(indx,BYTE);
  delay(200);
  indx++;
  if (indx==256) indx=-256;
}
```

Do you know why I cannot get the whole byte? I've tried different configurations for the termios.options and fcntl. Do you think that it is better to try some other library?

Thanks!

pd: I also realised that some numbers between 0 and 127 are not interpreted by the program. This numbers are 3, 17, 19 and some others I cannot remember.

Comment: have you correctly set the: parity, data bits, stop bits, handshaking?
teensy probably has different default values for these.

Comment: Yes parity will consume one bit of the byte if the message does not have parity but you say it does.